# "Unexpected token *" when attempting to run "vimagick/json-server" docker image with typescript

Tags: typescript, docker

As the title suggests, I am attempting to run the [vimagick/json-server](https://hub.docker.com/r/vimagick/json-server) docker image, with my server file being in typescript rather than javascript. Is there any way in which this can be done, as I am currently getting the following error:

```
/data/server.ts:1
import * as jsonServer from 'json-server';
       ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token *
```

I am running in docker-compose.yml in the standard way:

```
json-server:
    image: vimagick/json-server
    command: -H 0.0.0.0 -p 3000 -w db.json -r routes.json -m server.ts
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - ./support/json-server/db.json:/data/db.json
      - ./support/json-server/routes.json:/data/routes.json
      - ./support/json-server/server.ts:/data/server.ts
    restart: always
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the application expect a javascript file, you have to transpile your input file first, with a proper configured typescript builder, as mentioned [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html)